# Create sub cell in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, code-formatting

Is there any workaround to create sub-cells in Spyder?

E.g. I know that with

```
#%% Cell 1
```

I can create a new cell.

But is there a way to create a sub-cell which is grouped under the cell as in

```
# Cell 1.1
```

?

I have found [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7846) discussion which didn't look encouraging. But I wanted to give it a try and ask here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per the post linked, the feature you are asking has been implemented. I just tried it on my Spyder IDE version 4.1.3 and it works by using an increasing number of `%`. For instance

```
#%% Section 1
some code

#%%% Sub-Section 1.1
some more code

#%% Section 2
and so on
```