# Shortcut to creating a jupyter cell in a non-notebook python file in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

This might be the dumbest question here but I remember there being a 3 character string which would declare  a jupyter cell in a non-notebook python file in vscode and I can't seem to recall what it was and nothing ive tried so far gives a search engine result.

Comment: I believe what you’re looking for is  `#%%`.  This is simply an editor cell.  (Also works in Spyder). Not a duplicate, but a [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62910635/6340496).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a ipynb cell in a .py file it needs to look like this:

```
some code
....
....

# %%
text = "this code is now in a cell and can be run on it's own"
print(text)

# %%
# add another '# %%' before the rest of the code in your .py file so the cell above is isolated and can be run on it's own without running the rest of the program

more code 
...
...
...
```